# Update asp.net WebService reference from wsdl file?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wsdl

Is it possible in asp.net to update or create a web service reference from a wsdl file on our local drives?
If so, could you please describe it ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Haven't you tried doing so? If yes, what problem are you facing?

Comment: Well, Actually I don't know how we can do it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Follow these steps.

1. Open the `Solution`/`Project` in `Visual Studio`
2. Right Click on `Solution Explorer` on the project for which you want to add web reference.
3. Select `Add Service Reference`. (This will open a *Add Service Reference* dialogue box.)
4. Click on `Advanced...` button located at bottom of the dialogue box. (This will open another dialogue box named *Service Reference Settings*.)
5. Click on `Add Web Reference` button located at bottom of the dialogue box. (Again a dialogue box *Add Web Reference* would appear.)
6. Enter *OR* Copy & Paste full path for the `WSDL` file from your local drive as the `URL`.
7. Click on `Go` button besides the `URL` box.
8. Edit `Web Reference Name` if you want to.
9. Click on `Add Reference`.

And you are done.

Answer (score 4):

It's been long time from accepted answer. If you are using VS2019 you can simply click on the service and select "Update..."
[image]

Answer (score 0):

No need to add the service as Web Reference. You can do it setting the "Address" Field as the path of the file, for e.g.:

```
c:\contracts\mycontract.xml
```

and then "Go".

[image]