# How to update web reference in visual studio without access to the web service server

Tags: web-services, visual-studio, web-reference

We have a old app that uses some webservices to communicate with another server. only the app server has access to the **webservice server**. recently the owner of the webservice have made some changes to the webservices. Now we have to update our web references in the application. However, since our **dev machine** doesn't have any access to the **webservice server**, we can't just update the reference by right clicking and selecting "Update web reference". We have tried to create a dummy project in the **app server**, adding the reference to the dummy project, and then copying the wsdl/disco file to the actual dev environment. But it's giving error when we try to build the project. So, **how can we update the web reference in dev environment network access to the web service server?**

Comment: Seems I was googling the wrong terms. Found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929076/update-asp-net-webservice-reference-from-wsdl-file

Comment: Simplest way is to use a browser to browse the webservice url with `wsdl` prefix. i.e. `http://servername/restoftheurl/servicename.asmx?wsdl` and save the xml file as `servicename.wsdl`. copy it to local machine then add the wsdl file as web reference.