# how to reference web service with wsdl file only

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

I'm writing asp.net/c# project and need to call web services which other client provide. I've found that most people right click "service reference" to add url and use it. The thing is, I got .wsdl file only, is there any way to use it directly?
I've tried the [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710281/how-to-generate-service-reference-with-only-physical-wsdl-file) in here and they didn't work.
Thank you for answering.

Comment: Did you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18929076/update-asp-net-webservice-reference-from-wsdl-file

Comment: Yes I did, I fail in step 8, "Web Reference Name" textBox was blocked and the only button I can click is "Cancel".

Comment: @batyu did you get an answer?